# Parse a time span

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timespan

I'm trying to take a string `"00:04:55"`, and parse it into some sort of Ruby object so that I can get the total seconds. Something like in C# with a simple `timespan`.

Comment: You are losing a lot of potential answers because you do not describe what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Time.strptime` will do what you want (I think):

```
> require 'time' # not needed inside rails
> time = Time.strptime("06:04:55", "%H:%M:%S")
> time.sec
55
> time.min
4
> time.hour
6
> require 'active_support/core_ext' # not needed in rails
> time.seconds_since_midnight.to_i
21895
```

Comment: You don’t need ActiveSupport for this, just `require 'time'`. [`Time.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) is part of Ruby’s Standard Library.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick, it is not very elegant but it should do:

```
Date.parse(Time.now.strftime("%d")+' '+"00:04:55")
# => #<Date: 2013-10-26 ((2456592j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Date: 2013-10-26 ((2456592j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)

Comment: I guess I can make a wrapper for it :/. Sucks that Ruby has no OOTB solution for this kinda stuff.

Comment: The output that I get for this is: => Sat, 26 Oct 2013

Comment: Hmm. I can't read the output. I get a Date object back. x = Date.parse(Time.now.strftime("%d")+' '+"00:04:55")
# => #<Date: 2013-10-26 ((2456592j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
x.day # => 26
x.month # => 10